# jquery get() method , how exactly does it work?

Tags: jquery, arraylist, get, clone

I need to understand the difference between the clone() and get() method, I have this code and I would like to know if the get() method creates a duplicate of the array and if I can just use the clone() method instead?

```js
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
var lis = $("ol li").get().reverse();
$("ol").empty();
$.each(lis, function(i){
$("ol").append("<li>" + lis[i].innerHTML + "</li>");
});
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: why dont you check it yourself? you just have to read the documentation... Google is your best friend. https://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: As for me, it looks like something is wrong. jQuery `get()` method stands for `jQuery.ajax` GET synonym. Is this code working for you?

Comment: When you ask something, make sure you provide proper details, like the version of jQuery, and the HTML code used.  http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/19ejv9j9/  Either way it works for me in the fiddle.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Please check B. Kemmer's comment, this is not  the same thing as https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/.

Answer (score 0):

**When you ask something, make sure you provide proper details, like the version of jQuery, and the HTML code used.**

This works for me in the fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lis = $("ol li").get().reverse();
    $("ol").empty();
    $.each(lis, function(i) {
        $("ol").append("<li>" + lis[i].innerHTML + "</li>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/19ejv9j9/

I removed `(function($){})(jQuery);` from your code, because you don't need both this and `$(document).ready(function() {});`

This answer uses jQuery 1.8.3